# What's a word for someone who only does what they enjoy?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for someone who only spends time doing things they like, and shirk their important duties? I am trying to describe Mr. Frederick from Animal Farm, who had "a large, neglected, old-fashioned farm, much overgrown by woodland, with all is pastures worn out and its hedges in a disgraceful condition." It is implied that the farm has gone to such a state because he "spent most of his time in fishing or hunting". I can't think of the right word to describe this, and I'm not even positive there is one. I also want something that emphasizes doing something you enjoy *in place of* work that needs to get done.

Comment: A foot dragger....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word to describe someone who does whatever they please?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107378/word-to-describe-someone-who-does-whatever-they-please) or [A word for “negligence of duty or responsibility”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239047/a-word-for-negligence-of-duty-or-responsibility).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Georgia,

If you mean someone who only does what they enjoy in the sense of **indulgence**, then you could call such a person a *hedonist*.

If you mean someone who only does what they enjoy in the sense that he or she **avoids work**, then there are several idiomatic expressions you can use. Such as *goldbricker, shirker, malingerer, slugabed, spinebasher, loafer.* Note that these each come with a slightly different connotation for how the subject avoids work: makes excuses, pretends to do work while in fact doing none, fakes sick, stays late in bed. All suggest supreme laziness.

Answer (score 0):

A 'hedonist', perhaps.

Although widely understood to mean embracing a lifestyle of sex, drugs and rock'n'roll ("Folk Hedonsim"), Hedonism formally holds that pleasure and pain are the only things of ultimate importance and a [range of behaviours](https://iep.utm.edu/hedonism/#:%7E:text=There%20are%20two%20major%20types,or%20wrongness%20of%20an%20action.) can be called hedonistic.